# How do I take a rectangular shape and convert it into a circle?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs6

I would like to take an image eg: [image]

and convert that as accurately as possible to a circular version?

eg
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Image Open with Photoshop

First Option is this 
Filter > Distort > Polar Coordinates > Rectangular to Polar > OK

Second Option
Drag to a4 size artboard and Transform tool > Rotate 90% clockwise 
Transform tool > Make Big 
Filter > Distort > Polar Coordinates > Rectangular to Polar > OK